# SensorManager.registerListener - samplingPeriodUs being ignored

Tags: android, sensormanager

Disclaimer: There are many examples of this issue on SO. None of them answer my question.

I am trying to make my sensor `onSensorChanged` event fire every X secods.

Here is my code:

```
static long delay1 = 0;
public void sensorTester(){
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    final Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            long delay2 = System.nanoTime();
            long totaldelay = (delay2-delay1) / 1000000;
            Log.e(TAG, "DELAY from sensor: "+ totaldelay);
            delay1 = delay2;
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

The above works fine. `totaldelay` is printed as ~60ms.

The first issue here is that only `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` (~3ms registered) seems to make a difference. Every other option causes `onSensorChanged` to fire every ~60ms.

The second issue is that if I make a library with the above code, include the library (.aar) in my project and run it, `totaldelay` always comes out at +-3ms; no other option makes a difference.

The 3rd an final issue is that setting a custom value (e.g. 50000000 microseconds) is completely ignored (whether being executed in a library or not). This is despite the documentation making it clear that we can use a custom value:

> The desired delay between two consecutive events in microseconds. ***This
> is only a hint to the system.*** Events may be received faster or slower
> than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. Can be
> one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME,
> SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or the delay in microseconds.

Note the emphasis - I understand that it's a "hint" (whatever that means), but it is being completely ignored.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here and tell me how to fix this? I need my registered sensors to fire at a set interval.